# Break on a failing unit test Assert

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, breakpoints

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) version 17.2.4 with MSTest.TestFramework and TestAdapter version 2.2.10. When I start a test in debug mode, I would like it to break when a UnitTesting Assert Fails. Can someone tell me how to configure MSTest or my TestMethod or Visual Studio to do this?

If I need to switch to another test framework, that's fine, as long as it supports Visual Studio debugging.

Comment: [This is old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826241/break-the-debugger-on-assertion-failed), but maybe still a thing. Yay google.

Comment: First answer works! My google-foo must be off, I looked for quite a while but missed this one. If you want to use it (crediting Daryl Hoffman) to answer my question, I'll accept it.

Comment: For C++/Native Unit tests see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635350/981766